# Extract embedded image size (height, width) from PDF - python

Tags: python, image, pdf, resolution, dpi

how can I get the image size (height, width) of images inside a pdf?

Lets say I have a pdf page with 210x297 mm and an image inside of it. How can one determine the image size (e.g. image is 30x90 mm)?

Thanks

Comment: @KJ thanks for your reply. I played around with pdfimages. Maybe I can describe you my use case: I want to analyze images in pdf and retrieve/calculate the dpi of these image and give a warning if the image (with the size rendered in the pdf) has less than 300 dpi (bad quality for printing)

Comment: @KJ thanks for taking your time and providing me the link. i think i didn't understand the concept fully yet and need to research more about pdf and images.

I thought from knowing the pdf dimension and that it will be printed on A4, i can somehow calculate the dpi of the printed image.